# How to tell Alea GPU to AOT?

Tags: c#, .net, gpu, aleagpu

I want to AOT compile a kernel. I tried using the AOT attribute but looks like Alea.Fody was part of Alea v2 and was dis continued. Can Alea precompile code? If so, how do I tell Alea to precompile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alea.Fody and AOT compilation is discontinued in Alea GPU V3. Alea GPU compiler caches the compiled modules, so no repetitive compilation is required. To achieve precompilation, do a code warmup to force compilation and caching of the compiled modules. Be careful if you use delegates as they cannot always be indentified and lined back to already compiled delegate instances for the same function. This is a .net limitation. Alea GPU tries to do the best to cache delegates as well.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but does code warmup mean calling gpu.launch?

Comment: Yes, just execute the GPU kernel by calling it once, with e.g. gpu.launch